Microsoft Graph API higher then 5.44 - Attribute: Description - returns Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Serialization.UntypedArray
by using Microsoft Graph API 5.44 the field "description" (item.AdditionalData) is OK on Return.
If i use a API higher then 5.44 the Value of the Field is Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Serialization.UntypedArray.
Here is how i read...
User.Description = ReadAdditionalValueAttributeRS((Dictionary<string, object>)item.AdditionalData, "description"); 

Part of Code...
try
{
    System.Text.Json.JsonElement jo = (System.Text.Json.JsonElement)newProp.Value;

-->>  newProp.Value = Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Serialization.UntypedArray


    if (jo.ValueKind == System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.String)
    {
        sval = jo.GetString();
        sResult = sval.Replace(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbCrLf, @"\r\n");
        break;
    }
    else if (jo.ValueKind == System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.Array)
    {
        var elementContentEnumerator = jo.EnumerateArray();
        while (elementContentEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"You are now at property {elementContentEnumerator.Current}");
            sval += elementContentEnumerator.Current.ToString();
            sval += " ";
        }
        sResult = sval.Trim().Replace(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbCrLf, @"\r\n");
        break;
    }
}

Possible to check this value?
I currently switch back to Microsoft Graph API 5.44 while the value is OK.
I test with Versions 5.56, 5.57 and 5.58. The Return of value is not OK.

The class UntypedNode is base class for UntypedArray, UntypedString, UntypedInteger, UntypedBoolean, etc. All Untyped classes have GetValue() method which returns the collection of untyped node, string, int, or bool value.
Check if the newProp.Value is either UntypedArray or UntypedString and then use GetValue() to read the value.
try
{
    if (newProp.Value is UntypedString untypedString)
    {
        sval = untypedString.GetValue();
        sResult = sval.Replace(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbCrLf, @"\r\n");
        break;
    }
    else if (newProp.Value is UntypedArray untypedArray)
    {
        foreach (var item in untypedArray.GetValue())
        {
            if (item is UntypedString itemUntypedString)
            {
                sval += itemUntypedString.GetValue();
                sval += " ";
            }
        }
        sResult = sval.Trim().Replace(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbCrLf, @"\r\n");
        break;
    }
}

I'm afraid that working with UntypedNode is not well documented by Graph SDK team.

Thanks for that solution. It was also changed after 5.44.
I make further Tests next days.
